# Django showing Id of model in browser url instead of model name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I created models for companies in my new application in django and have also created the instance for it to show detail page for each company. But when a company is clicked, it shows the id of the company instead of the name in URL like this:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/2/

is there a way I can make it return the company name instead like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/stackoverflow/

this is the code for my model and am using function based views for this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
Online_Merchant = 'merch'
Education = 'edu'
Transportation = 'trans'
Hospitalism = 'hosp'
Healthcare = 'health'
Construction = 'const'
Blog = 'blog'
Finance = 'fin'
Media = 'media'
Government_Agency = 'agency'
Other = 'other'
Manufacturing = 'manufacturing'
sector = [
    (Online_Merchant, 'Online Merchant'),
    (Education, 'Education'),
    (Transportation, 'Transportation'),
    (Hospitalism, 'Hospitalism'),
    (Healthcare, 'Healthcare'),
    (Construction, 'Construction'),
    (Blog, 'Blog'),
    (Finance, 'Finance'),
    (Media, 'Media'),
    (Manufacturing, 'Manufacturing'),
    (Government_Agency, 'Government Agency'),
    (Other, 'Other')
]
Free = 'Free'
Premium = 'Premium'
package = [
    (Free, 'Free'),
    (Premium, 'Premium')
]


user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Company User')
company_sector = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=sector, default=Online_Merchant, verbose_name='Sector')
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
company_description = models.TextField()
company_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company_logos', blank=True, null=True)
company_address = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
rating_array = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), size=0, default=list)
average_rating = Int_max.IntegerRangeField(default=0, verbose_name='Avg', min_value=1, max_value=5)
total_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
company_website = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
company_email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
package_chosen = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=package, default=Free)
company_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
advert = models.BooleanField(default=False)
premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    """Returns the url to access a particular instance of the model."""
    return reverse("detail", kwargs={ "id": self.id })

def __str__(self):
    return self.company_name

def __repr__(self):
    return self.company_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield**) is designed for this. the django admin will help populate it as well.

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...other model fields...
    company_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, allow_unicode=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular instance of the model."""
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={ "slug": self.company_slug })
```

**admin.py**

```
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"company_slug": ("company_name",)}
    ...admin code...
```

and to use it in a query:

```
company = Company.objects.get(company_slug=kwargs.get('company_slug')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [ path('<slug:company_slug>/', views.dynamic_url, name='detail'), ]
```

Comment: I have just done as instructed above but it returns an error:   NameError at /companies/2/
name 'kwargs' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/2/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: 
name 'kwargs' is not defined

Comment: kwargs should be passed in to the view, also the urls need to be updated to allow for slugs instead of id.

Comment: my url: urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:company_id>/', views.dynamic_url, name='detail'),
    
    ]

on the template: <p><a class="text-decoration-none " href="{% url 'detail' comp.id %}">Click to View Full Details</a></p>

Comment: my view: def dynamic_url(request, *args, **kwargs):
    responses = Response.objects.all()
    company = Company.objects.get(company_slug=kwargs.get('company_slug'))

what the model looks like now: 
 company_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, allow_unicode=True, null=True)# used to get company name in url instead of ID

    def get_absolute_url(self):# used to get company name in url instead of ID
        """Returns the url to access a particular instance of the model."""
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={ "slug": self.slug })

Comment: it gives me this error: 

MultipleObjectsReturned at /companies/12/
get() returned more than one Company -- it returned more than 20!
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/12/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value: 
get() returned more than one Company -- it returned more than 20!

Comment: The urls.py names the variable that will appear in kwargs.  ` path('<slug:company_id>/', views.dynamic_url, name='detail'), ]` would create `kwargs.get('company_id')`

Comment: The template url should be `{% url 'detail' comp.company_slug %}`

Comment: Still returning more than one company. Same error.

Comment: Are the slug fields all empty?

Comment: The fields are all empty except for the one am using to test the solution. I had to put value for the slug field to enable me access it else when you hover at it, it will show none ie. 127.0.0.1:8000/companies/none

Comment: And If you add the slug in the url?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. I think this prepopulated_fields = {"company_slug": ("company_name",)}   is not prepopulating the company_slug field with the value of company_name.

Comment: Yes. It’s a js helper function in the admin.  If you already have data, you must add the slugs manually or look into management commands.

Comment: OK, Thank you, Michael. It works fine now. Best regards.